# Удалить 1-2 слова

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть 2 текста

1. Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy 4 Hybrid синий

   ```
   preg_replace("/\\s\\S+$/u", "", $NAME);
   ```
2. Чехол `Spigen SGP` для `Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid` белый (SGP10454)

как удалить 2-ом пункте 2 слова "белый и (SGP10454)"
но чтобы в 1ом пункте не удаляло 2 слово...
т.к нет (SGP+5цифр)

чтобы оставалось

1. Чехол `Spigen SGP` для `Galaxy 4 Hybrid` (норм)
2. Чехол `Spigen SGP` для `Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid`

---

Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid белый (SGP10454) нужно удалить **2 слово из конца** строки если присутствует (SGPXXXXX) а если его нет то только 1 то есть "белый"

Comment: Для использования регулярки в таком случае, нужна какая-то закономерность. В этих двух строках, еще как-то её можно найти, но если допустить, что название могут значительно отличаться по маркам телефонов (*что скорее всего и будет*), то затея становиться бессмысленной.

Comment: @vasbkadg - Напиши, пожалуйста, то, какие строки мы получаем на входи и какие ты хочешь видеть строки на выходе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так, если следовать тз.

```
<?php

$str1 = 'Spigen SGP для Galaxy 4 Hybrid синий';
$str2 = 'Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid белый (SGP10454)';
$str3 = 'Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Galaxy белый (SGP10454)';

function repName($str){
    return preg_replace('#\s[^\s]+(\s?\(SGP\d+\))?$#', '', $str);
}

print_r(array(repName($str1), repName($str2), repName($str3)));
```

http://ideone.com/owOCbx

Answer (score 2):

Довольно странное у ваc регулярное выражение, вы хоть чуть-чуть понимаете что означает комбинация метасимволов **`\s\S+`** ?

Решение вашей задачи на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Qsz3hE)

```
$str1 = 'Spigen SGP для Galaxy 4 Hybrid синий';  
$str2 = 'Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid белый (SGP10454)';

function repName($str){
    return preg_replace('#(?<=Hybrid).*$#u', '', $str);
}

print_r(array(repName($str1), repName($str2)));
```

Comment: @ua6xh, а вот и не угадали ;) Слово "синий" тоже надо срезать. По сути, тут только один выход - удалить всё, что после "Hybrid"

Comment: @Deonis - тут противоречия какие-то.

Делал по вот этой фразе:

>как удалить 2-ом пункте 2 слова "белый и (SGP10454)" но чтобы в 1ом пункте не удаляло 2 слово... т.к нет (SGP+5цифр)

Comment: @ua6xh, На тот каламбур я уже не стал ориентироваться, и смотрел на то, какой ТС хотел бы результат в итоге. Хотя, не факт, что и там всё однозначно ))

Comment: @Deonis - ждем комментариев автора)

Comment: По сути, тут только один выход - удалить всё, что после "Hybrid",
да именно так нужно, но суть заключается в том что тексты разные...

Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid белый (SGP10454)
нужно удалить 2 слово из конца если присутствует (SGP10454)
а если его нет то только 1 тоесть "белый"

Comment: SGP10454 могут быть разное цыфры.... (SGP+5цифр)

Comment: @vasbkadg - обновил решение, см. по ссылке в ответе.

Comment: ну это и значит "удалить все, что после `Чехол Spigen SGP для Galaxy Note 3 Neo Hybrid`"

Comment: @NoName - вы про **\s\S+** ? =)

Comment: > но суть заключается в том что тексты разные...

@vasbkadg, Собственно, об этом я и писал в первом своем комментарии. Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь, но ведь возможно, что где-нибудь в следующей строке вообще не будет слова Hybrid, да и артикул может чем-то отличаться, да и в принципе, будет речь не о Самсунге, а об LG, к примеру?

Comment: удалить сначала  (SGPXXXXX)  а потом последнее слово ? в смысле можно группой это сделать